# MySQL update a column with select and if else

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i want update a column, when the select from another table is not empty, with the selected date from the another table and when its empty with a constant date.

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Messe_Tag (
ID integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Datum date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Messdiener (
ID integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Letztes_dienen date DEFAULT '2017-01-01',
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);

CREATE TABLE Messe (
ID integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Datum integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Datum) REFERENCES Messe_Tag(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Dienst_Messe (
ID integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Messdiener integer,
Messe integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Messdiener) REFERENCES Messdiener(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Messe) REFERENCES Messe(ID)
);
```

I want select the last date in `Messe` from a `Messdiener`. `Messdiener` and `Messe` is related over `Dienst_Messe` and the date from `Messe` is related to `Messe_Tag`. When the select return an empty result i want update `Messdiener.Letztes_dienen` with the constant date `'2017-01-01'`. When the select returns a date i want update with that date.

Example data of tables:

```
INSERT INTO Messe_Tag(ID,Datum)VALUES(1,'2017-07-11');
INSERT INTO Messe_Tag(ID,Datum)VALUES(2,'2017-05-23');

INSERT INTO Messdiener(ID,Name)VALUES(1,'Basti');
INSERT INTO Messdiener(ID,Name)VALUES(2,'Alex');

INSERT INTO Messe(ID,Datum)VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO Messe(ID,Datum)VALUES(2,2);

INSERT INTO Dienst_Messe(ID,Messdiener,Messe)VALUES(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Dienst_Messe(ID,Messdiener,Messe)VALUES(1,1,2);
```

I try this with the following update statement but isn't do what i want:

```
UPDATE Messdiener MES
LEFT JOIN Dienst_Messe DM ON DM.Messdiener = MES.ID
LEFT JOIN Messe M ON M.ID = DM.Messe
LEFT JOIN Messe_Tag MT ON MT.ID = M.Datum
SET MES.Letztes_dienen = CASE
WHEN MT.Datum IS NOT NULL
THEN MT.Datum
ELSE '2017-01-01' END
WHERE MES.ID = ?;
```

With `MES.ID = 1` i want update `Messdiener.Letztes_dienen` with `2017-07-11` because this is the last date. And with `MES.ID = 2` i want update with `2017-01-01` because the `Messdiener` with `ID = 2` hasn't a date in `Dienst_Messe -> Messe -> Messe_Tag`.

My update statement update the column but not with the latest date `(2017-07-11)` but rather with the oldest date `(2017-05-23)`. If `MT.Datum` is empty the statement update the column `Messdiener.Letztes_dienen` to `2017-01-01` successfully.

I think that i need a `ORDER BY` in my update statement for the problem with the oldest date but i dont't know how i implement this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `Messdiener` SET `letztes_dienen` = (
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(MT.Datum), '2017-01-01') FROM 
                  `Dienst_Messe` DM 
        LEFT JOIN `Messe`     M  ON M.ID  = DM.Messe
        LEFT JOIN `Messe_Tag` MT ON MT.ID = M.Datum 
    WHERE DM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
)
WHERE `id` = ?;
```

Comment: I have try do modify your code because the max value can be in 2 another tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have try to modify your code because the max date can be in three another tables.

```
UPDATE Messdiener SET Letztes_dienen = (
SELECT IFNULL(
(SELECT MAX(D.Datum) FROM (
SELECT MT.Datum Datum FROM Dienst_Messe DM
LEFT JOIN Messe M ON M.ID = DM.Messe
LEFT JOIN Messe_Tag MT ON MT.ID = M.Datum
LEFT JOIN Messdiener ON DM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
WHERE Messdiener.ID = ?
UNION
SELECT MT.Datum Datum FROM Weihrauch_Messe WM
LEFT JOIN Messe M ON M.ID = WM.Messe
LEFT JOIN Messe_Tag MT ON MT.ID = M.Datum
LEFT JOIN Messdiener ON WM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
WHERE Messdiener.ID = ?
UNION
SELECT MT.Datum Datum FROM Kreuz_Messe KM
LEFT JOIN Messe M ON M.ID = KM.Messe
LEFT JOIN Messe_Tag MT ON MT.ID = M.Datum
LEFT JOIN Messdiener ON KM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
WHERE Messdiener.ID = ?
UNION
SELECT MT.Datum Datum FROM Assistent_Messe AM
LEFT JOIN Messe M ON M.ID = AM.Messe
LEFT JOIN Messe_Tag MT ON MT.ID = M.Datum
LEFT JOIN Messdiener ON AM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
WHERE Messdiener.ID = ?
) AS D)
, '2017-01-01'
)
WHERE ID = ?;
```

The `SELECT IFNULL(....) AS D), '2017-01-01');` returns the right date but in the update clause its fire an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 27
```

Line 27 is the last line with `WHERE ID = ?;`
Why? Can you help me?

A antother try from me was this:

```
UPDATE Messdiener SET Letztes_dienen = (
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(MT.Datum), '2017-01-01')
FROM Messe_Tag MT
LEFT JOIN Messe M ON M.Datum = MT.ID
LEFT JOIN Dienst_Messe DM ON DM.Messe = M.ID
LEFT JOIN Weihrauch_Messe WM ON WM.Messe = M.ID
LEFT JOIN Kreuz_Messe KM ON KM.Messe = M.ID
LEFT JOIN Assistent_Messe AM ON AM.Messe = M.ID
WHERE DM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
AND WM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
AND KM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
AND AM.Messdiener = Messdiener.ID
)
WHERE ID = 46;
```

But this set `Letztes_dienen` straight to `'2017-01-01'`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) (w/o repetitions) which contains all tables which have the date.

```
-- I assumed that the structure of the tables is the identical.
CREATE VIEW all_data_view AS
    (SELECT id, datum from Kreuz_Messe) UNION (SELECT id, datum FROM Messe);
```

The query which checks the result:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(MT.Datum), '2017-01-01') FROM 
              `Dienst_Messe` DM 
    LEFT JOIN `all_data_view` AD  ON AD.ID  = DM.Messe
    LEFT JOIN `Messe_Tag` MT ON MT.ID = AD.Datum 
WHERE DM . Messdiener = 1;
```

Thus, by modifying the DML from the first answer (replace table `Messe` with view `all_data_view`) you achieve your goal.